# How to avoid my tooltip text (dis)appearing below my pricing table?

Tags: css, table, tooltip

Hi folks i am adding tooltips to each feature of my price table, but as you can see, a big part is hidden below the next column of my pricing table. How can i put it in front?
I have tried to add z-index -1 to that element but that did not help.

[image]

Comment: This question my be better suited for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). What framework are you using to render your tooltips? Could this be an overflow issue on the parent containing div? It could be a number of CSS related issues, none of which are a Wordpress issue. Try posting on or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) with accompanying CSS and HTML example code.

Comment: @joshmoto hi Josh i am using Elementor. Thanks I will